# Offset in a comparator's input

Tags: analog, comparator, dc-offset

This is probably a basic question which i'm stuck with:

Why should there be offset at the input signals?

=> We have offset voltage of 1V on both the signals, when i remove the offset i get very weird result (result are given below)!

[image]

1. Weird result (without offset)
   [image]
2. normal result (with offset)
   [image]

Comment: I think you're going to have to clarify what you mean by "very weird results".

Comment: Also, either add an -ve supply or read the datasheet very carefully abouth the common mode input voltage range - it may not include the -ve rail.

Comment: @brhans just uploaded the results ..... :)

Comment: For 5Vdc reduce both V1,V2 to (5-1.5)=3.5Vpp max if both are biased at (3.9-0.3)/2= 1.8Vdc otherwise if biased at 2.5V max swing= 2.5Vpp MAX. approx depending on tolerances

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what weird results you are getting, it could be that you didn't check the input common range.

[image]

The input common mode voltage (average voltage of the inputs) has to be about 0.2V above the negative rail.

As pointed out by Carloc, a detailed description of the behavior of the comparator over the input voltage range can be found in the datasheet. I've added Carloc's screenshot below

[image]

Comment: just uploaded the pictures :D ... have a look please

Comment: It looks like your signal is not only outside the common mode range but also below the negative rail. That does not work, the results you are getting are ok. You have to fix the input signal, i.e. add an offset.

Comment: Although you definition of common mode voltage as average is generally okay, it does not apply in this  case and in any such opamps or comparators specifications. Both V+ and V- inputs have to be within those limits as clarified [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25163354/Cattura%20%282%29.JPG)

Comment: Good point, I'll update my answer!